# TextRenderer doesn't draw some Symbol characters

Tags: c#, drawtext, text-rendering

I am trying to draw some text using both `Graphics.DrawString` and `TextRenderer.DrawText`. I use the *Symbol* font but the outputs are not the same - `TextRenderer` doesn't handle the symbols "less than or equal to", "greater than or equal to" and "not equal to" (byte values `0xA3`, `0xB3`, `0xB9`) - it draws boxes instead of them. Other special symbols are drawn correctly, though - for example "square root" `(0xD6).` I use the same font with both methods. What can I do to make the `TextRenderer` draw these symbols correctly?

**EDIT:**

I am running .NET 4, Windows 7 Ultimate with Czech language version (but I've tested it with English version and it looks the same).

Below is the code from my test app:

```
private void panelDrawString_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    byte[] array = new byte[] { 0xA3, 0xB3, 0xB9, 0xA4, 0xD6, 0xB4, 0xB0 };
    string s = new string( array.Select( b => (char) b ).ToArray() );

    using( StringFormat sf = StringFormat.GenericDefault )
    using( Font font  = new Font( "Symbol", 14, FontStyle.Regular ) )
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        e.Graphics.DrawString( s, font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, panelDrawString.ClientRectangle, sf );
    }
}

private void panelTextRenderer_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    byte[] array = new byte[] { 0xA3, 0xB3, 0xB9, 0xA4, 0xD6, 0xB4, 0xB0 };
    string s = new string( array.Select( b => (char) b ).ToArray() );

    using( Font font  = new Font( "Symbol", 14, FontStyle.Regular ) )
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText( e.Graphics, s, font, panelTextRenderer.ClientRectangle, panelTextRenderer.ForeColor );
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: The output of the code above]

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Improve your question by documenting the .NET version and the Windows version and post a code snippet.

Comment: yeah..Its working fine.. have you used these bytes while rendering or copy paste the symbols from anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

May be a little late in posting a reply.

As stated in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/557898/CustomplusDrawingplusTextplususingplusspecificplus) the GdiCharSet is the cause of your problem. Microsft acknowledges it does does not support all versions of every platform.

A Font is made up of glyphs (like '√' for the radix of the square root) and a codepage (like 0xD6  for the radix of the square root) The rectangle glyph is drawn for any codepage value that is unknown.

In your situation however the codepage value used by TextRenderer and DrawString is different to the codepage value you think is used.

The string you create that holds the characters also transforms the codepage to UFT16. 
That means the value 0xA3 is transformed to [0x2264](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/index.htm) when the value is typecasted to a char value and placed in the string.

The DrawText and DrawString both use a different approach for printing the glyphs. The DrawString prints your expected result because it translates the named value 'LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO' to the glyph. DrawText however prints the glyph belonging to 0x2264.

For your purpose you should just use DrawString.